# Python 3.6 numpy reshape works but the values contain e

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, reshape

This is my original matrix:

```
print(ma1)
[0.20744994, 0.14539546, 0.10465959, 0.08974831, 0.0833745, 0.05821741, 0.05399565, 0.048799813, 0.046413686, 0.045579262, 0.29622522, 0.23889951, 0.12952305, 0.10534078, 0.09048214, 0.06320238, 0.038907345, 0.03251371, 4.403997e-05, 4.3995205e-05, 0.2012324, 0.13538276, 0.13010766, 0.117249586, 0.096130796, 0.054276276, 0.053859193, 0.050035723, 0.044707138, 0.044018902, 0.21539064, 0.13680255, 0.10455292, 0.09108675, 0.08697859, 0.084347665, 0.0827448, 0.06820062, 0.049759883, 0.039898306, 0.18320614, 0.16905661, 0.08368087, 0.069563076, 0.067597985, 0.066892244, 0.061399546, 0.054606315, 0.049824238, 0.045746554, 0.35845336, 0.15175189, 0.09139741, 0.0782547, 0.07662025, 0.05772785, 0.035782516, 0.032826394, 0.032347433, 0.029752351, 0.19313496, 0.10973337, 0.09762528, 0.08410441, 0.077503815, 0.06584602, 0.054904133, 0.051901218, 0.04822838, 0.042950567, 0.4457341, 0.14356656, 0.07977738, 0.07553261, 0.06597889, 0.051388923, 0.05051739, 0.048244715, 0.03579711, 3.1358708e-05, 0.19721146, 0.18309301, 0.10019932, 0.08062746, 0.06745502, 0.06674413, 0.060487617, 0.05569927, 0.049575083, 0.049429215, 0.16310705, 0.091974616, 0.08310301, 0.08160683, 0.059281424, 0.04982662, 0.04924009, 0.04637339, 0.046048205, 0.045636863]
```

I want to turn it into a 10X10 matrix and when I use np.reshape

```
na = np.reshape(ma1, (10, 10))
```

The output is pretty weird

```
[[2.07449943e-01 1.45395458e-01 1.04659587e-01 8.97483081e-02
8.33745003e-02 5.82174100e-02 5.39956503e-02 4.87998128e-02
4.64136861e-02 4.55792621e-02]
[2.96225220e-01 2.38899514e-01 1.29523054e-01 1.05340779e-01
9.04821381e-02 6.32023811e-02 3.89073454e-02 3.25137116e-02
4.40399708e-05 4.39952055e-05]
[2.01232404e-01 1.35382757e-01 1.30107656e-01 1.17249586e-01
9.61307958e-02 5.42762764e-02 5.38591929e-02 5.00357226e-02
4.47071381e-02 4.40189019e-02]
[2.15390638e-01 1.36802554e-01 1.04552917e-01 9.10867527e-02
8.69785920e-02 8.43476653e-02 8.27447996e-02 6.82006180e-02
4.97598834e-02 3.98983061e-02]
[1.83206141e-01 1.69056609e-01 8.36808681e-02 6.95630759e-02
6.75979853e-02 6.68922439e-02 6.13995455e-02 5.46063147e-02
4.98242378e-02 4.57465537e-02]
[3.58453363e-01 1.51751891e-01 9.13974121e-02 7.82546997e-02
7.66202509e-02 5.77278510e-02 3.57825160e-02 3.28263938e-02
3.23474333e-02 2.97523513e-02]
[1.93134964e-01 1.09733373e-01 9.76252779e-02 8.41044113e-02
7.75038153e-02 6.58460185e-02 5.49041331e-02 5.19012176e-02
4.82283793e-02 4.29505669e-02]
[4.45734113e-01 1.43566564e-01 7.97773823e-02 7.55326077e-02
6.59788921e-02 5.13889231e-02 5.05173914e-02 4.82447147e-02
3.57971117e-02 3.13587079e-05]
[1.97211459e-01 1.83093011e-01 1.00199319e-01 8.06274563e-02
6.74550235e-02 6.67441264e-02 6.04876168e-02 5.56992702e-02
4.95750830e-02 4.94292155e-02]
[1.63107052e-01 9.19746161e-02 8.31030086e-02 8.16068277e-02
5.92814237e-02 4.98266183e-02 4.92400900e-02 4.63733897e-02
4.60482053e-02 4.56368625e-02]]
```

All of the value in my matrix is replaced by some strange value?
Or I should use some other way to change it into a 10X10 matrix?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the output of `reshape`. Take a look at the first value in both your input and your output arrays. `2.07449943e-01` is an example of [scientific notation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/scientific.html). The `e-01` at the end just means "multiply the preceding number by 10 to the power of -1". So the first value in your reshaped array is really `.207449943`, which is the same as the first value in your input (aside from a rounding error in the final digit).

You can stop Numpy from displaying scientific notation by running this line before any of your code:

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

Numbers like `2e4` are valid literals in Python. If you were to enter the following into a Python command line:

```
x = 2e4
print(x)
```

you'd get this output:

```
20000.0
```

which is equal to:

```
2.0*(10**4)
```